# Could anyone pls suggest good sources to learn this stuff well?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

I'm really struggling with star and delta connection and AC circuit analysis in general. Wanted to know if you guys have any good resources teaching this (pic below) properly.
[image]

Comment: There's nothing really special about any of that. But it involves two or three different separate things so you should Google around for each one separately until you understand each one on its own without being complicated by the others: delta-wye phase current stuff, three phase power with PF =1,  and apparent+reactive power stuff separately until you find an explanation for each one that you understand separately.

Comment: Thank you so much @DKNguyen

Comment: I would recommend this tutorial: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/dcp_10.html

Comment: @tlfong01 I don't think the OP needs resistance conversions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This site has a range of related tutorials - [start here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-10/three-phase-y-delta-configurations/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone writes that the draw is \$40\:\text{A}\$ and \$415\:\text{VAC}\$ then it is reasonable to assume that these values are independent measurements: that the current is measured as an RMS value with a meter designed for that purpose and that, separately, the voltage is measured as an RMS value again by a meter designed for that purpose.

This in no way means that the current and voltage are in-phase (meaning that the current rises at the same moments that the voltage also rises, and so on.) They may be out-of-phase with each other. It just means that if you ignore voltage and measure the RMS current, or ignore current and just measure the RMS voltage, then you have two independent measurements but you do NOT know their relative phase with each other. That's a missing piece of information.

The apparent power is always just the two independent measurements multiplied by each other. So in this case the apparent power is \$16.6\:\text{kW}\$. I've already told you that you don't know the relative phase (angle.) But you do know one part of the triangle: its hypotenuse which equals the *apparent power*.

The power factor tells you the ratio between the *actual power* and the *apparent power*. So they are saying that the cosine leg of the triangle is 80% of the hypotenuse. With that in place you can form up the entire triangle, now.

[image]

The above is developed from the input (the power supply into the machine.) You will need to take into consideration its efficiency, too. (Which likely relates to the actual/active power.) But does this help out? Can you take it from here?

Comment: YUPP!! It did clarify all these terms and what they actually mean! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When it says "phase" current, this is as opposed to "line" current. For delta and wye systems you have phase current and line current. For voltage you have line-to-neutral voltage and line-to-line voltage.

For a wye system, the current on the lines going into it is the same as the currents on the each phase, but for a delta it is different because once the lines get into the delta, they split up into two different phases.

[image]
https://www.oao-7.xyz/ProductDetail.aspx?iid=62612327&pr=25.88

It's sort of the reverse for the voltage: in a delta the voltage between two lines is the same as the voltage across each phase, but in a wye it's different because the voltage between two lines gets spread across two phases.

[image]
[image]
https://www.etechnog.com/2021/10/line-phase-voltage-current.html

Since a delta has no neutral point to measure line-to-neutral voltages against you can't really measure unless you fake it with an equivalent circuit, but you can calculate the equivalent. It's kind of buried inside the delta.

It's not 50-50 though since nothing is in phase. The factor for both voltage and currents is \$\sqrt 3\$ for a balanced system. You can look around to see why this is in vector diagrams for three-phase systems.

Comment: Awesome! I really do appreciate all the time you put into that!!!